# bias and variance trade off related question

Tags: statistics, mathematics

I am having difficulty to understand the expected squared errors formula in [this website](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-bias-variance-tradeoff-165e6942b229):

$y=f(x)+e$  true regression line

$\hat{y}=\hat{f}(x)$   your estimated regression line

$error(x)=\bigg(\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)]-f(x)\bigg)^2+\mathbb{E}\bigg[(\hat{f}(x)-\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)]\bigg]^2+var(e)
        =bias^2+variance+\text{irreducible error}$

my question is what is the best way to understand bias and variance from this mathematical equation?

my understanding of variance here is:

assume you collect a sample with 1000 records and you generate regression line based on this sample. You get a model: $\hat{f}(x)=1+2x$

so at a given x value, for example: $x=1$ then $\hat{f}(x)=1+2*1=3$

then you re-sample another 1000 records and generate regression line:

$\hat{f}(x)=2+3x$

when $x=1$, $\hat{f}(x)=5$

you repeat this process for N times (assume N is a large number and close to infinity)

then your $E[\hat{f}(x=1)]$ is $(3+5+\dots+N)/N$

assume your $E[\hat{f}(x=1)]$ is $5.5$

once you have calculated $\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)]$ for a given value of x=1, you should be able to compute $\mathbb{E}\bigg[\hat{f}(x)-\mathbb{E}[\hat{f}(x)])^2\bigg]$

$((3-5.5)^2+(5-5.5)^2+...)/(n-1)$

my interpretation above is focusing on variance of $\hat{Y}(x)$ at a each given $x$-point(re sampling to get $\hat{y}(x)$)

but my instinct tells me I should calculate based on only one set of data (1000 records) and calculate $\mathbb{E}[\hat{Y}(x)]$ at different x point.

please let me know which one of interpretation is correct or if both are wrong, please explain using this formula how I should interpret the terms in this formula.

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The [bias of an estimator $\hat{f}(x)$ of $f(x)$ is **by definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator#Definition):

$$Bias(\hat{f},f)(x)=E[\hat{f}(x)]-f(x)$$

which is some definite (not-random) function $\phi(x)$.

Why this is so? The intuitive way to understand it is that estimation itself is a *random process*. Given **random data will produce a random estimation**. However the *expected estimation* is $E[\hat{f}(x)]$, so it is only natural to define **bias as the difference between expected estimation and true value**.

In case the bias of the estimator $\hat{f}(x)$ (for $f(x)$) **is zero**, in other words:

$$E\left[\hat{f}(x)\right] = f(x)$$

Then the estimator is called **unbiased**. It has no (systematic) bias in the estimation process and the expected estimation coincides with the true value. If furthermore, this estimator has minimum possible variance is called **minimum variance unbiased estimator**. All these are part of the basic theory of statistics.

The linked tutorial you mention simply computes the total **Mean Square Error (MSE)** by the various **components it can be split into** (a general theorem for any type of estimation process):

**MSE = (irreducible noise error) + (estimator variance) + (bias squared)**

or in other words:

$$MSE(x) = Var[\epsilon] + Var[\hat{f}(x)] + Bias(\hat{f},f)(x)^2$$

The estimator variance is **the same formula as for any other random variable** and is certainly part of the total **MSE**.

[**Derivation:**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff#Derivation)

1. Suppose $y = f(x) + \epsilon$, $E[\epsilon]  = 0$, $Var[\epsilon] = \sigma^2$
2. For any random variable $r$ we have $E[r^2] = Var[r] + E[r]^2$ (by the definition of variance).
3. For any non-random value $c$ we have $E[c] = c$, $Var[c] = 0$
4. $E[y] = E[f(x) + \epsilon] = E[f(x)] + E[\epsilon] = E[f(x)] = f(x)$
5. Similarly $Var[y] = Var[\epsilon]$ (expand the definition and use previous facts)
6. Since $\hat{f}$ and $\epsilon$ can be taken as independent, we can write the total error as:

${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}
\operatorname {E} {\big [}(y-{\hat {f}})^{2}{\big ]}
&=\operatorname {E} {\big [}(f+\varepsilon -{\hat {f}})^{2}{\big ]}\\[5pt]
&=\operatorname {E} {\big [}(f+\varepsilon -{\hat {f}}+\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])^{2}{\big ]}\\[5pt]
&=\operatorname {E} {\big [}(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])^{2}{\big ]}+\operatorname {E} [\varepsilon ^{2}]+\operatorname {E} {\big [}(\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}})^{2}{\big ]}+2\operatorname {E} {\big [}(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])\varepsilon {\big ]}+2\operatorname {E} {\big [}\varepsilon (\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}}){\big ]}+2\operatorname {E} {\big [}(\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}})(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]){\big ]}\\[5pt]
&=(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])^{2}+\operatorname {E} [\varepsilon ^{2}]+\operatorname {E} {\big [}(\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}})^{2}{\big ]}+2(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])\operatorname {E} [\varepsilon ]+2\operatorname {E} [\varepsilon ]\operatorname {E} {\big [}\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}}{\big ]}+2\operatorname {E} {\big [}\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}}{\big ]}(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])\\[5pt]
&=(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])^{2}+\operatorname {E} [\varepsilon ^{2}]+\operatorname {E} {\big [}(\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}]-{\hat {f}})^{2}{\big ]}\\[5pt]
&=(f-\operatorname {E} [{\hat {f}}])^{2}+\operatorname {Var} [\varepsilon ]+\operatorname {Var} {\big [}{\hat {f}}{\big ]}\\[5pt]&=\operatorname {Bias} [{\hat {f}}]^{2}+\operatorname {Var} [\varepsilon ]+\operatorname {Var} {\big [}{\hat {f}}{\big ]}\\[5pt].
\end{aligned}}}$

Why **MSE**? It is a smooth suitable metric for the accuracy which has nice analytic properties. Other types of error are also possible.

Further reading (and derivations and references therein):

1. [Bias of an estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator)
2. [Bias–variance tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff)
3. [Derivation of the Bias-Variance Tradeoff](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/mlsc/Notes/Lecture4/BiasVariance.pdf)